# Control Windows Security popup when accessing a website via VBA Excel

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

Since an Excel file, I would like to connect that intranet of our company. My problem is that the login and the password are to be written in Windows Security popup.
I don't know how to manage that without using SendKeys... Another problem linked to that is that sometimes, the popup appears again, even if the login and password are good. Do youhave an idea to the way to catch such an event?

[image]

Comment: Here is a solution with SendKeys.

I lauch a script contained in a VBS file at the beginning of the macro.
The script waits for the appearance a the popup and send the login/password in using SendKeys.

My problem, now, is that the script is still running after the end of the macro...

Does somebody have a solution to kill the script?

Comment: I found: in giving a duration limitation when I call the script...
Shell "wscript.exe ""path\file.vbs"" //T:20" 'example with 20s

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution with SendKeys. I lauch a script contained in a VBS file at the beginning of the macro. The script waits for the appearance a the popup and send the login/password in using SendKeys.